# How do I include an `<img>` in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor

I have tried numerous ways based on various answers, But I can't seem to get this to work.

I have the file structure as follows:

```
-client
--components
---thecomponent.js //the file
--img
---small.png //the image
```

Inside thecomponent.js

```
// all these don't work
<button><img src={require("../img/small.png")}/></button>
<button><img src={"../img/small.png"}/></button>
<button><img src="../img/small.png"/></button>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: I have tried every suggestion provided. Looks like I am in the correct direction, but I am still getting the same error when using require. It says:

> Cannot find module '/public/img/small.png'
>       at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=0969a31…:133)

Any ideas?

**EDIT2:** I've found the problem. Actually I am using meteor-react, not pure react, and therefore am asking the wrong question. Both paqash and Rishabh are right about the answer, but in meteor the "public/" word as to be dropped when referencing, as stated in their [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories):

> All files inside a top-level directory called public/ are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include public/ in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference public/bg.png as . This is the best place for favicon.ico, robots.txt, and similar files.

Comment: What is the error when you use these methods? Image not found? Also, using absolute paths is usually better since it's much easier to see where the location of the import is, and it means all of a components imports won't break when you change its location in the project hierarchy. Otherwise you can end up with crap like this `<img src="../../../../../images/someImage.png" />`

Comment: You need an image loader to ensure that when you import an image it returns the correct url for it; i.e. https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load images from the http server with absolute path and not via relative. You can also use a CDN to host images.

add a public directory and then load image like `<img src="/public/img/small.png" />`

```
-client
--components
---thecomponent.js //the file
-public
--img
---small.png
-index.html
```

Comment: The use of absolute vs relative path makes absolutely no difference to caching. Relative paths are resolved to absolute paths before caching is considered.

Comment: agreed. updating the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`var small = require('../img/small.png')`

`<img src={small} />`

This works for me